# how to test svm classifier?

Tags: matlab, classification, libsvm

I'm using svm for human action recognition. I use "kth" database which has 25 people doing 6 different actions(walking, jogging, running, boxing, handclapping and handwaving) in 4 different scenarios. so I have 600 data samples (Motion History Image)(100 samples for each action).

I trained 6 different one-vs-all svm for 6 actions, for example:

--for training the running class I used:

--80 samples from running samples;

--500 samples from other classes;

So I saved 20 samples from running for testing the classification.
But my results are so great that made me sure that I have made a mistake in testing (90% success while other papers have 63.5% in their best shots).

What should I do for testing the svm classifier?

additional information:

Each video:
30 seconds, 20 fps, size of each frame 160*120

Algorithm:

1)  Extracting MHI feature from all videos (25 people,4 scenarios,6 actions,30 seconds each)so 360000 samples collected.

2)  Selecting 600 samples (1 from each video)

3)  Reshaping all the samples(1*19200)

Training:
    Do 4 to 6 for each class

4)  80 samples as class +1

5)  500 samples as class -1

6)  Calculating “w” and “bias” with libsvm for each class

Test:
    Now we have 1 “w” and “bias” for each 6 classes.

7)  Use the untrained MHI feature as input

8)  Calculating “W * input + bias” for each class

9)  The winner class is a class which sign(W * input + bias) >0

Comment: Probably, instead of training multiple one-vs-all classifiers, try using a single multi-class SVM model for training and testing on all six actions at once.

Comment: thanks. multi-class svm? i thought svm is an binary classifier and i should use one-vs-all or one-vs-one svm to make it a multi-class classifier. can you give me more clues?

Comment: libsvm (https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/) is capable of handling multi-class SVM training and classification for you. Also, I think you are still confusing the terms features and data samples. As pointed out by Parag, read a book or take a machine learning course to understand the concepts better.

Comment: thanks a lot. that problem came from my English not my knowledge :D i will correct that

Comment: i think my problem is solved. i'll collect more samples then re-run my program.20 samples are not enough for the test, specially when i selected the best feature manually.

Answer (score 0):

I see many problems. I also recommend you to take a machine learning course, or read a book to understand concepts better.

1. Why do you use 600 features, if there are different scenarios, you can't include different features for different scenarios. You feature vector should be able to cope up with the variations in all scenarios.
2. Do you concatenate features of different people when classifying an action. If so, then that is also kind of wrong. Imagine I give you a sample which has one action, one scenario done by one person. How will you classify this at the test time?
3. You say that you used 80 features from running class when classifying "running" action. So, will you use 80 features for boxing and 500 from the rest while classifying boxing? If so, this is wrong too. When you classify a sample, you don't know its class. You should treat all classes in the same way when you do feature extraction.
4. You say, "So I saved 20 features from running for testing the classification". If you are getting good performance by doing this, then this is wrong as well as weird. If you have trained your classifier with 80 features (or 580), then you should test with the same number of features. I am not sure how the SVM does not produce an error. The weight vector will be 580-D and you test feature vector is 20-D, obviously `w^T*x` should give dimension mismatch error.

**What you should do?**

1. Derive a feature which explains variation in all scenarios. For example, if you want to detect humans, you don't want to include "color" as a feature, since everybody's clothes are of different color. So this is a bad feature. You can't concatenate features from all actions too. What I mean is the following: you can't devise a different feature extraction method for running, boxing etc. How would you know the class of the test sample? You wouldn't, and so you cannot apply a action-specific feature extraction method. For example, you cannot detect extract feature describing leg motion for classifying running, and extract feature describing hand motion for boxing. That's wrong.
2. Number of features while training and testing should be same in case of SVM classifier.
3. You cannot train 6 different classifiers (on different train sets) and then use only one of them during testing. For example, you can't train a classifier for running vs. boxing and then use that to classify running. There are specific protocols on how to do multi-class classification. Two of them are "one-vs-all" and "one-vs-one". Read them. You can use libsvm package if you don't want to implement them.

**Rule-of-thumb:** Whenever you develop a feature extraction method, think, if you can apply this method when you are given just one sample. Remember, you are not allowed to use the training set. Assume it doesn't exist on your computer.

Comment: thank you for your answer. 1) i used 1 feature (Motion History Image). i had 600 extracted MHI feature. 2)yes i did. the first 80 features were labeled as class 1 and the rest(500 features) labeled as -1(one vs all) 3) yes i did the same for other classes because its supervised classification. in this case i know the input for training. i just left 20 feature untrained from each class, so that i may use them as test input.  4)each feature dimension's is 1*19200, 580 is the number of training data.

Comment: i just added my algorithm, this may help you to understand my question better